# Time limit exceeded and performance: what's the difference?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have two tags that have quite a large amount of overlap in their definitions:

- [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)

  > Performance is a subset of Optimization: performance is the goal when you want the execution time of your program or routine to be optimal.
- [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded)

  > When the code scales so poorly in the face of large inputs that it cannot complete in a reasonable amount of time, use this instead of the [performance] tag.

---

And so [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) is simple. If you want to increase the performance of the program then you tag it with this.

However, if it fits [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) then you need to tag it with that instead. Which is when:

- "When the code scales so poorly in the face of large inputs"

  We don't really know how large 'large' is. And so [Counting ways to fit bottles in crates](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/108594) which has an input of \$n=30,k=20,K_i=i\$. Fits in this tag.
- "cannot complete in a reasonable amount of time"

  We have no clue what the time limit is, or even if it changes. And so this mostly comes down to wanting better performance.
- "use this instead of the [performance] tag"

  Since the overlap here seams to be overly large, it seems we want to tag all questions with [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) rather than [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance).

---

And so how should we deal with these tags? What's the difference? Should they be synonyms, or something else?

Comment: To be honest, both are meta-tags of the same kind as the old [naming] and other tags that describe an area of concern. [time-limit-exceeded] describes performance (likely algorithmic) in the context of an online judge or other online coding challenge à la Project Euler.

Comment: @Mat'sMug But it's not limited to coding challenges either. Take the last 7 TLE questions, half of them aren't challenges, and it's regulars that are tending to add the tag...

Comment: Eh, I'd just burn them both. Wouldn't be the first meta-tags to meet Trognor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) is for a *need*, whereas [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) is for a *want*.

Yes, there are times when both apply, but even then, a question should only use the one that fits best.  It's probably most likely that [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) will be used with a programming challenge, whereas [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) would be used elsewhere.

That said, I think they should stay separate (maybe even burninated), and we could clean up both tags if needed.  We could also tweak the wikis for a bit more clarity regarding usage.

Comment: I personally like seeing either of them, so I'd vote for a cleanup and against a burnate...

Comment: Time-limit-exceeded is also more commonly used with the tag challenge. Where one needs respect some kind of maximum run-time duration in seconds

Comment: I really like the [tag:time-limit-exceeded] because you get basically only code challenges which are working but too slow to pass. The [tag:performance] can burn though, basically all questions would be eligible for that. Would be nice to see how many questions have both compared to each one.

Comment: I can get behind just burninating [tag:performance].  It's another leftover "meta" tag that we somehow kept, which is also currently synonymized with [tag:optimization].  I've already cleaned out all the locked questions (which impedes burnination), so it's good to go(ne).

Answer (score 3):

Please **do not delete** [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance).

This tag indicates that the OP that made the question seeks answers that address performance issues with the code.

**Do not delete** [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) either, I would rather create a synonym with [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance).

I admit when I first saw the [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) I was intrigued. Like I said in the comments to the answer of @Jamal this tag is mostly used along with [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge).

If we take a look at the question count per tag is as follows (data taken in moment of writing this answer)

[time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) - 484

[time-limit-exceeded +  programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded+programming-challenge) - 236

So about 50% of the questions where the [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) are applied are in fact [programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge) questions.

---

I can't tell if making a distinction between [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) and [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) is important or not. However I can at least tell that a question containing [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) should also contain [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance).

Hence my previous suggestion of creating a synonym. The benefit in doing so is there will be no ambiguity whatsoever when using each tag.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, :) I whole heartedly agree with you, on wanting them to stay, and making them synonyms. I'm not sure I agree with having both on a single question, say you have a Python question, I don't really want to see '[tag:python] [tag:python-3.x] [tag:performance] [tag:time-limit-exceeded]', as yeah, there should probably be another tag there. Also you may be interested in [Jamal's request to burninate them](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7321) :)

Comment: Minor point, but: 50% of [time-limit-exceeded] are *known* to be [programming-challenge] questions. I haven't looked through them to verify, but at a quick guess, the majority of the rest probably *are* actually programming challenge questions, just without the tag to indicate that.