# Would burninating [performance] bring good performance?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag has *over 5000 questions* which is also the master tag of *4 other tags*.  It can also be considered a "meta tag", much like previously burninated tags such as [[naming] and [refactoring]](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/should-we-do-something-about-our-meta-tags).  Also, as brought up in [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/time-limit-exceeded-and-performance-whats-the-difference) just recently, it can be confused with [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded), despite some of their somewhat specific differences.  For [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) in particular, it can still be implied in every question as it could still be brought up in a review.

Should we get rid of this one, or could there somehow still be some use to it?

Comment: Since I kinda know what meta tags are, but forget a bit, [here's the blog page the describes meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Answer (score 7):

I see three main trade-offs in most code.

- Performance
- Memory usage
- Readability

And so when a question is posted on Code Review I think they want a trade off of all three. And so I normally try to make the code as readable as possible whilst keeping the performance and memory usage the same. If there is a way to increase any of them without a significant loss to another then I'd recommend that too.

If the question is tagged with either; [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance), or [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded), I'd try to get the best performance I can, with little regard for readability or memory usage.

And so I think there is a benefit to this tag.

---

However is it a Meta Tag? Where [Jeff Atwood's post describes these](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

> If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.

Ignoring our requirement for at least one language tag. If we had a question only tagged with [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance), you wouldn't be able to tell anything about the question. Only what the OP wants from the answers.

And so yes, it's a meta tag, but I still think it holds value as a tag, as described in the first section.

Comment: [tag:time-limit-exceeded] still has more specific uses, so I'm not putting that on the table right now.  This post is just for [tag:performance], so [tag:time-limited-exceeded] would need its own post.

Comment: @Jamal I'm not sold by 'has more specific uses'. But as this is about [tag:performance], I'll edit this down a bit to not include [tag:time-limit-exceeded].

Answer (score 3):

There are 344 followers of the [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) tag.

Are there experts in performance? Yes.

Is it likely that a question tagged [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) gets extra attention from specific users? Yes.

It should stay.

Comment: What do you have to say about it being a meta tag and our current stance on meta tags?

Comment: @Mast Sure, it's a meta tag. But we should let it be. Just like we still have the beginner tag.

Answer (score -2):

I agree it's a meta tag. Just about everybody wants better performance and otherwise it will either be clear from the question or it's tags ([memory-optimization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory-optimization) comes to mind).

[time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) has a reason to exist, as mentioned in the post you linked. [performance](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) does not. Get rid of it.

[image: Trogdor]

Comment: I don't really get what you mean when you bring up [tag:memory-optimization]. Is it one that should go, like Performance, or have I missed the point?

Comment: @Peilonrayz No, it's one of the obvious cases where performance is probably not the asker's main concern. That tag should stay IMO.

Comment: I know about many cases where performance is not a very important factor. Sometimes, whether something takes 2 milliseconds or 20 milliseconds doesn't matter.